# Changing month names of a highchart plot

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts, lang

I'm trying to change the short month names of a highcharts plot produced with rcharts. I would like to have the German names. This is what I tried:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(Sys.Date() + 1:365) * 86400000, y = c(1:365))
h <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", data = dat, type = "line")
h$xAxis(type = 'datetime', tickInterval = 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)
h$lang(shortMonths = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
                       "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"))
h
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how rcharts works but the `lang` properties are not in the chart builder exactly. They are in [`Highcharts.setOptions.lang`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang). You would have to find the rcharts equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can not find the rcharts equivalent for this. I'm not sure if it even exists.